# How can I use @font-face to load Google web font?

Tags: css, font-face

I want to use a Google Font called Cormorant Garamond, but I can't seem to get the @font-face command to do what I want. I've followed thes instructions (https://coderwall.com/p/5vrdkg/google-fonts-using-fontface-in-your-css ) and I now have a declaration in one of my (multiple) css files which looks like this:

```
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Cormorant Garamond Regular'), local('CormorantGaramond-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/cormorantgaramond/v3/EI2hhCO6kSfLAy-Dpd8fd8lWqVXdZDPPgQrkuJ8lbib3rGVtsTkPsbDajuO5ueQw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF; 
}
```

This is right at the top, just before the 'body' declaration

Then further down I have this:

```
.collection-editorial p {
    font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', Arial;
    line-height: 110%;
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

When I load the page (using Chrome) it obviously is displaying Arial. Yet using the inspector I see no errors in the Console, and looking at the "calculated" css rules, I can see that it should apparently be Cormorant Garamond (ie the css rule seems to be applied correctly). Yet clearly it is not coming out right. I must be missing some trick, but what?

Comment: Did you include the font file(s)? Why not just use the google CDN so you don't have to define your own `@font-face` properties? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWZjyy

Answer (score 0):

To embed that font into a webpage, copy this code into the `<head>` of your HTML document.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then, use the following CSS rules to specify this family:

```
font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
```